# Transformations of vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

So i was watching some videos online about Transformations and vector valued functions. Now the conclusion that i came with was that a transformation (lets say  (T: ${R^2}$  $\rightarrow$ ${R^2}$) ) is actually a transformation of 2 dimensional space, where if given a vector input, it shows the "movement of the vector" withing the transformation of the two dimensional space. Essentially a morphing of space is happening and as space bends, shrinks, turns etc we see where the vector lands and thats our transformation.

Now my question is this reasoning correct? , as other places seem to only state that a transformation is a function that takes a vector and spits out another vector.

Also if my reasoning is correct would a transformation across dimensions e.g (T: ${R^3}$  $\rightarrow$ ${R^2}$) ) be conceptualised as transforming three dimensional space into two dimensional space??.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your reasoning is correct.

The transformation deforms each individual input vector to produce an output vector.

But we can also think about what happens when the totality of *all* input vectors is deformed simultaneously. Then, the transformation does in fact deform space (in some sense).

As you say, a mapping from $\mathbb{R}^3$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$ actually "squashes" all the vectors of $\mathbb{R}^3$ onto a plane.

When thinking about transformations, it's often a good idea to figure out the effect of the deformation on some simple shape, like a square. A linear mapping from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$ will always deform a square into a parallelogram. The parallelogram might be a degenerate one, like a line or even a single point, but still a parallelogram in some sense. Similarly, a linear mapping from $\mathbb{R}^3$ to $\mathbb{R}^3$ will always deform a cube into a parallelipiped.

For more general transformations, it helps to think of space as a cube of jello. The transformation will bend/warp/stretch/twist the cube. Any points or lines or vectors inside the jello will get carried along as the jello deforms.

There is an [excellent series of YouTube videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kjBOesZCoqc) that provide insight into the geometry of linear algebra.

Comment: Oh ok thank you very much, these geometric interpretations are rarely ever discussed, just a mere " it takes a vector and spits out another".

Comment: Indeed. I much prefer "it takes a square and spits out a parallelogram".